# What is the blood level evolution of a intramuscular injection?

Tags: blood-tests, injections

Suppose an intramuscular injection of a substance is done on a patient. What would be the form of the graph of the blood concentration of this substance over time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is taken from a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/pharmacology-toxicology-and-pharmaceutical-science/intramuscular-route) on Science Direct.

> The intramuscular route is used where effects are desired over a
>   longer period of time than can be expected after intravenous
>   injection, for drugs that are too irritant to be given subcutaneously,
>   or for oily solutions, which cannot be given intravenously. Drugs in
>   aqueous solution are often absorbed rapidly from intramuscular sites.
>   Drugs dissolved in oil (‘depot’ injections) are absorbed more slowly
>   and absorption can continue for weeks after injection.

Generally, the intramuscular (IM) route results in slower absorption and a longer duration of action than intravenous (IV) injections.

However, there is a wide variability depending on the preparation and the drug involved.

Here is a qualitative graph showing a comparison of plasma concentration against time.

[image: Comparison of plasma concentration over time for various routes of administration]

The branch of pharmaceutical science concerned with the absorption and elimination of drugs is called [pharmacokinetics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacokinetics).